# Adding a count to a menu item in grails

Tags: grails

Can I ask what I hope is a simple question please.

Can I add a total number of records to my menu item from in the view?

I assume i could use something like

```
<g:Set var="totalcount" value="${mylist.countall()} or similar" />
```

but I cant find the answer anywhere.

```
Home
Mylist (4)
mylist2 (7)
```

Is heat Im after, any help much appreciated for this newbe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly set your variables

```
Mylist (${myVariable})
Mylist2 (${myList.size()})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you get your data as paged results with criteria as the following code:

```
def results = Account.createCriteria().list (max: 10, offset: 10) {
    like("holderFirstName", "Fred%")
    and {
        between("balance", 500, 1000)
        eq("branch", "London")
    }
    order("holderLastName", "desc")
}
```

You will receive only 10 results, but also the totalCount property of results, which gives you the number of total rows without paged.

```
results.totalCount
```

You can see more about this on the [documentation](http://docs.grails.org/2.1.0/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html)